# Algebraic proof of 2nd inequality of Global class field.

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

s there any 'explicit' proof, preferably without the use of cohomology, of second inequality of global field?

By second inequality I mean $[C_K:N_{L/K}C_L]\leq [L:K]$ where $C_K$ is idele class group of $K$. In particular I would like to know proof for the case where char($K)= [L:K]=p$ where $p$ is a prime.

I know in the book Class field theory by Artin and Tate there is a proof but wondering whehter there are more explicit proof, using artin-schreier extension or something like that.

---

The proof I know of (not necessarily understand it well)

1. Analytic proof using L-function and so forth (I have practically no knowledge on them and at the very least I am not too interested in this approach for now)
2. Artin and Tate- It must be a good method, since every text which I found which does not deal with $p$-extensions of function field (which is practically all the text), but I am really struggling to understand it well. Nothing wrong with this method, but I was hoping there is a 'better' approach somehow as it is a fairly old text.
3. Class Formation II by Kawada Satake- Uses Duality using Witt vectors and actually proves that for any characteristic $p$ field, there is such duality and certain object defines a class formation. And using this, class field theory restricted to $p$-extension of function field can be proved and second inequality is proved on the way. However from what I can tell it relies on Cohomology heavily and ideally I want to see a proof without it. (Like what Neukirch did)

---

Cross posted at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/195715/explicit-description-calculation-of-norm-group-of-ideles-of-characteristic-p-g

Comment: What makes a proof of this inequality "explicit"? It was first proved by Weber using L-functions and the language of generalized ideal class groups rather than ideles. See Lang's Algebraic Number Theory.

Comment: To be honest I am not sure what I mean. Proving in the spirit of Neukirch's abstract method I suppose. I am also aware of analytic method but looking for algebraic approach.

Comment: Whoops, I did not notice you were specifically asking about degree p in characteristic p. Lang's treatment via Weber's method does not cover that case. That case was first treated by Witt. See http://www.rzuser.uni-heidelberg.de/~ci3/klkall.pdf, especially the last three sections for Witt's contributions (this is where Witt vectors were first created).

Comment: @KCd I suspected that there should be a result using Witt vectors. I have yet to find one though. I guess it is quite possible that Witt published a paper but the fact that it's in French (I think?) makes it very hard to access for me.

 In fact I do know a paper which (indirectly) gives the result by Kawada-satake. It heavily relies on cohomology though.

Comment: Witt was German and wrote in German, not French.